# How to allow input file filed in swagger

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I make a nest application and I try to make an endpoint that allows the user to upload the file and I want the upload file field to show in swagger.
This is my function in  Controller file:

```js
    @Post('upload')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file);
    }
```

But in my swagger UI , it doesn't show the upload file field
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following decorator above the action

```
@ApiImplicitFile({ name: 'file' })
```

So instead of  -

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
console.log(file);
}
```

change to -

```
  @ApiImplicitFile({ name: 'file' })
    @Post('upload')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file);
    }
```

Comment: Where do we put these codes?

Comment: What do you mean?